# Create a git repo using an alias from terminal

Tags: linux, git, bash, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

Hey there I want to create a git repository like this:

```
curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
```

But I want to do it using a alias in terminal (Ubuntu), like

```
alias newRepo = curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"$1"}';
                git remote add origin git@github.com:USER/$1.git;
```

So after in the terminal I type:

```
newRepo test
```

And it creates the repo and add the remote "origin".

Comment: You can't with an _alias_. Use a _function_ instead (you're nearly there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that like this:

First create a script **newRepo**:

```
#!/bin/bash
user="$1"
reponame="$2"
if [ "$user" = "" ]; then
read -p "Enter Github username: " user
fi
if [ "$reponame" = "" ]; then
read -p "Enter Github Repository Name: " reponame
fi
curl -u "$user" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "{\"name\":\"$reponame\"}"
```

Then make alias:

```
alias newRepo=/pathtothenewReposcript
```

Now you can use:

```
newRepo username reponame
```

to create a new repository in github.

Comment: The script approach is certainly easier to do and control than my `git config alias` solution. +1

Comment: I'm trying to use it but I get this back

    {
       "message": "Bad credentials",
       "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
    }

Comment: @T04435 it says `Bad credentials`. Probably a problem with authentication.

Comment: @Jahid Yes it was, but thanks for your anwser now I can save Lot of time, Thanks once again

Comment: @T04435 https://github.com/neurobin/DemoCode
Some codes are not properly tested and totally un-organized, though I use these codes time to time.

Answer (score 2):

You can find good examples of git alias involving a shell function in "[Git alias for displaying the GitHub commit url](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-alias-for-displaying-the-github-commit-url:49c0e1af-69e8-4b6e-89a6-066b4834cda3)".

The trick is to find the right combination of single quotes/doubles quotes/escape, when typing the git config alias command.

In your case, considering you have a '!', you cannot surround your git config alias parameter with double-quotes if you are in bash ([no '!' within double quotes](http://qntm.org/bash))

That leaves you with [`$` single quote (`$'...'`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48122/7490)), which accepts '`!`', and escaped single-quotes (again in bash; that would be easier in zsh):

As an example:

```
vonc@bigvonc MINGW64 /c/Users/vonc
$ git config --global --replace-all alias.newrepo2 '!f() { echo \'e\'; }; f'
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

vonc@bigvonc MINGW64 /c/Users/vonc
$ git config --global --replace-all alias.newrepo2 $'!f() { echo \'e\'; }; f'
```

The final command would be:

```
vonc@bigvonc MINGW64 /c/Users/vonc
$ git config --global --replace-all alias.newrepo $'!f() { curl -u \'USER\' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d \'{"name":"$1"}\'; git remote add origin git@github.com:USER/$1.git; }; f'
```

That being said, if you typed `curl -u 'USER' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"xxx"}'`, it would ask you for the password for '`USER`'.

That means:

- maybe '`USER`' shoud be `$(whoami)`
- and... a `git config` multiple-command alias doesn't seem to support well waiting for an argument to be entered in stdin...

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass parameters to aliases.  Create a bash function.

Comment: You can, you just have to finagle the alias so the arguments git supplies textually at the end get assigned as parameters for a function you give in the alias body

Comment: Ok, but then you still use a function in the alias, so why use alias at all ? With pure bash aliases, you can't use parameters.

Comment: My apologies, the question was tagged git and VonC answered with a git alias, which does have advantages (namespace, automatic per-template specialization, blabla) and has the additional advantage of actually allowing function definitions, unlike bash aliases, which don't.